# How do I start IRB console from a rake task?

Tags: ruby, rake, irb

I'm trying to write a rake task that will set up an environment mirroring my project.

```
task :environment do 
  require 'rubygems'
  require 'sequel'
  # require 'my_projects_special_files'
end

task :foo => [:environment] do
  require 'irb'
  IRB.start
end
```

Leads to irb complaining that "foo" doesn't exist (the name of the task)

```
10:28:01:irb_test >> rake foo --trace
(in /Users/mwlang/projects/personal/rake/irb_test)
** Invoke foo (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute foo
rake aborted!
No such file or directory - foo
/opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/irb/input-method.rb:68:in `initialize'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/irb/input-method.rb:68:in `open'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/irb/input-method.rb:68:in `initialize'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/irb/context.rb:80:in `new'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/irb/context.rb:80:in `initialize'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:92:in `new'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:92:in `initialize'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:57:in `new'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:57:in `start'
/Users/mwlang/projects/personal/rake/irb_test/Rakefile:9
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

IRB.start is looking at ARGV which contains the task name(s) from the rake command line. Try clearing ARGV first.

```
require 'irb'
ARGV.clear
IRB.start
```

Comment: That was indeed the problem!  Thanks for answering

Comment: Thanks too! @MichaelLang you should accept this answer already.

Comment: There is a more straightforward way to do this in Ruby 2.4.0; see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

As of Ruby 2.4.0, you can do this:

```
require 'irb'
binding.irb
```

Comment: nice to know!  I should probably note the original question and accepted answer solves for Ruby 1.8.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem when running my task like that. Setting it the default task solved the problem but it did not help with the bug. Here: what i did

```
task :console do
  exec 'irb -I lib -r startingscript.rb'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The rake file contents are below and it is named Rakefile.
Run it from terminal with rake test:console

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rake'

namespace :test do
desc "Test Task"

 desc "Load stuff in IRB."
 task :console do

   exec "irb -r rubygems -r sanitize" #require multiple gems by typing -r gemname

 end

 end
```

once you've executed the rake test:console, irb pops up and you can see that it works by using Sanitize's clean method.
    Sanitize.clean "some text"

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there must be a problem with how you defined your task. What happens if you change

```
task :foo => [:environment] do
```

to

```
task :foo => :environment do
```

Comment: Same thing happens whether I have [:environment], just :environment, or nothing at all.  If I change the name of the task to "bar" then IRB fusses about "bar" not being found, so its somehow picking up on the task name and trying to find a file or folder for it.